# Pattern in openAPI spec not being generated

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I am trying to generated a separate class with the following definition in my OpenAPI spec but he keeps generating it with a string and no bean validation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5Y7p.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1msF.png)

THe generated code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhirz.png)

Can someone help me on generating a class for the enterpriseNumber instead of a string and preferably with a beanvalidation

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not upload images of code. To understand why, please read the following article: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors. Thanks.